# Solr DataImporter config exception

Tags: jdbc, solr, dataimporthandler

Starting Apache Solr Admin (Win7), after configuring Solr DataImportHandler to connect to SQL Server using JDBC SQLServerDriver, produces following error. MS Sql JDBC Connector sqljdbc4.jar is placed in bin, and lib folder of Solr.

```
org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter init
SEVERE: Could not start SOLR. Check solr/home property
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: FATAL: Could not create importer. DataImporter config invalid
...
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Exception occurred while initializing context
 at ...
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog...
```

solrconfig.xml has:

```
<requestHandler name="dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

data-config.xml is:

```
    <dataConfig>
        <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" name="hy"
                    driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"  
                    url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=test;responseBuffering=adaptive;" 
                    user="test"
                    password="test"
                    readOnly="true"/>

    <document name="listings">
        <entity name="listings" dataSource="hy" pk="ListID"
          query = "SELECT ListID, Description, PostDate FROM Listings"
          transformer="DateFormatTransformer">
            <field column="PostDate" name="PostDate" dateTimeFormat="yyyy-MM-dd" />
        </entity>
    </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Delete extra spaces before  in data-config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a "/" in front of your requestHandler name:
`<requestHandler name="/dataimport" ...`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem but I have the '/' before dataimport. I understand that this has something to do with xml config docs but everything looks fine. can there be any other reason other than xml doc error for this case?